# How to serialize the a struct to a class in java

Tags: java, serialization, struct

I am using Debezium to monitor CDC in a database and the following code displays the output.

```
private void handleChangeEvent(RecordChangeEvent<SourceRecord> sourceRecordRecordChangeEvent) {
    var sourceRecord = sourceRecordRecordChangeEvent.record();
    log.info("Key = {}, Value = {}", sourceRecord.key(), sourceRecord.value());
    var sourceRecordChangeValue = (Struct) sourceRecord.value();
    log.info("SourceRecordChangeValue = '{}'", sourceRecordChangeValue);
}
```

Is there a way to serialize the output to a class or a json structure ?

```
Struct{before=Struct{id=1,email=john.doe@acme.com,fullname=John Doe},after=Struct{id=1,email=john.doe@acme.com,fullname=Kjell Paula Jan Moens},source=Struct{version=1.9.4.Final,connector=mysql,name=customer-mysql-db-server,ts_ms=1683702844000,db=customerdb,table=customer,server_id=1,file=binlog.000004,pos=2251,row=0,thread=24},op=u,ts_ms=1683702844884}
```

Comment: Use a serialization library.